# axon event handler in another class

Tags: eventhandler, axon

I am using axon 2.3.1 , I have one aggregate class

```
public class MyAggregate extends AbstractAnnotatedAggregateRoot<MBAggregate>   {


@AggregateIdentifier
private MyId Id;
private Circle circle;
EventDispatcher a=new EventDispatcher();

public MyAggregate() {
}

@CommandHandler
public MyAggregate(NewCommand command ) {
    apply(new SmallEvent(command.getId(), command.getCircle()));
}

@CommandHandler
public MyAggregate( StoreDestinationsCommand command ) {
    apply(new BigEvent(command.getId(), command.getCircle()));
}
//And some event handlers like

   @EventHandler                                                                                                                             
   public void onSmallEvent(SmallEvent event)    
   {
    //Some logic here
   }
   @EventHandler                                                                                                                             
   public void onBigEvent(BigEvent event)    
   {
    //Some logic here
   }
```

Now i want these event handlers to be contained in some other class and be called when that event get triggered

```
public class EventContainer {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -6640657879730853388L;



  @EventHandler                                                                                                                             
   public void onSmallEvent(SmallEvent event)    
   {
    //Some logic here
   }
   @EventHandler                                                                                                                             
   public void onBigEvent(BigEvent event)    
   {
    //Some logic here
   }
```

I tried putting them in another class but those events are not triggered.
Any idea  how can i achieve this in AXON.
Thanks,

Comment: Hey. Mind giving more information? Like how you are using Axon? With Spring? If you get any errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You need to tell Axon that your `EventContainer` class can handle events published to an Event Bus.

```
   AnnotationEventListenerAdapter.subscribe(new EventContainer(), eventBus);
```

**Longer Answer:**
To achieve what you want to do, taking a step back to understand the building blocks provided by Axon to build a CQRS application would be of help...

Axon Framework is a framework that provides you with the building blocks to build a CQRS application. And a CQRS application, in layman's term is just an architecture that allows you to separate the part of your application that executes actions (write) and the part that display your application state (read).

To do this Axon provide a couple of building blocks.

**1) CommandBus**
The Command Bus is the component within Axon Framework that provides the mechanism of having commands routed to their respective Command Handlers. For example from your code sample, the `@CommandHandler` annotation on `MyAggregate` means that when `NewCommand` is created, your `MyAggregate` method would be called. The Command Bus is the component that makes this possible.

**2) CommandGateway**
Command GateWay is a component that exposes a more friendly API to the CommnadBus. While you are not required to use a Gateway to dispatch Commands, it is generally the easiest option to do so.

**3) EventBus**
The EventBus handles the dispatching mechanism for events. Much like the Command Bus does for Commands. So when you have `apply(new BigEvent(command.getId(), command.getCircle()));` which fires a `BigEvent` it is the Event Bus that is responsibly for making sure the necessary event handler is called. And in your case, the question you are asking is how to have the Event handlers defined in a separate Class and still have Axon be able to route the events to them.

This is quite straight forward. I would assume you are not using Spring and that you are manually setting up the Axon components together by hand and creating the `NewCommand` that triggers the `SmallEvent` that you want to handle in `EventContainer#onSmallEvent` method. A way to get this done may look like this:

```
public class FireCommandAndCaptureEventInAnotherClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We use the simple Command Bus.
    // There are different implementation available. For example axon provides a distributed command bus that can be used to distribute commands over multiple nodes
    CommandBus commandBus = new SimpleCommandBus();

    // The friendlier API to send commands with
    CommandGateway commandGateway = new DefaultCommandGateway(commandBus);

    // You may skip this as it may not pertain to your question but since we are using event sourcing, we need a place to store the events. we'll store Events on the FileSystem, in the "events" folder
    EventStore eventStore = new FileSystemEventStore(new SimpleEventFileResolver(new File("./events")));

    // a Simple Event Bus will do
    EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();

    // You may skip this as it may not pertain to your question but since event sourcing is used in this example we need to configure the repository: an event sourcing repository.
    EventSourcingRepository<MyAggregate> repository = new EventSourcingRepository<MyAggregate>(MyAggregate.class,
                                                                                         eventStore); 

    // Sets the event bus to which newly stored events should be published 
    repository.setEventBus(eventBus);

    // Tells Axon that MyAggregate can handle commands
    AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.subscribe(MyAggregate.class, repository, commandBus);

    // This is the part you need. With this We register an event listener to be able to handle events published on to an event bus. In this case EventContainer.
    AnnotationEventListenerAdapter.subscribe(new EventContainer(), eventBus);

    // and let's send some Commands on the CommandBus.
    commandGateway.send(id, circle);
  }
}
```

With this setup, the handlers in the `EventContainer` would be able to react to events triggered from `MyAggregate`

Comment: Thanks a lot @dade for your answer and putting your valuable time to answer this question its helpful.

Comment: @dade if we are using spring, then how should be proceed about it. 

I"ve tried to register it using Component annotation and using EventHandler annotation on the specific method which i want to be triggered, however, this is not happening. Will be great if you can shed some light on this.